# MySQL Aurora and AWS S3: Need an alternate way of MySQL's "LOAD DATA" for loading document data from S3

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, amazon-aurora

I need to import data from files stored in S3 into an MySQL Aurora db.

I have Eventbridge setup so when the file is added to S3 it fires an event that calls a lambda.

The lambda needs to import the file data into MySQL.  The MySQL "LOAD DATA FROM S3" feature would be great for this.....  but.... you will get the error:  `This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`.

LOAD DATA has a lot of limitations such as this, it cannot be be in a stored procedure, cannot be in dynamic SQL (really needed here).  I cannot find a hack work-around for this and need an alternate way to import data directly from S3 to MySQL.  I don't want to move the data from S3 to Lambda to MySQL as that extra step in the middle adds a lot of exposure for failure.

Does anyone know any good ideas (and even not so good) for moving data from S3 to MySQL Aurora?

Thanks.

Comment: If switching DB engine is an option then take a look at this solution for AWS Aurora PostgresSQL,  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether the user has permission to import data, which requires **AWS_LOAD_S3_ACCESS** permission
2. Examples of import statements can be referred to as follows:

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3://mybucket/data.txt'
     INTO TABLE table1
     (column1, column2)
     SET column3 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

3. For more detailed information, please refer to
   https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html

Comment: This works from a connection in mysql workbench, but not from AWS Lambda function which uses the same user credentials.  So it not a permission issue or is there something I'm missing?